# Rails: Adding scope in a model using column values of same model in where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to rails. I am trying to create a scope using where clause. In that where clause i want to use column values of same model. But i don't know the correct way of doing that. Please help me out. Here's the code snippet:

```
attr_accessible :booked_qty,
                :cancelled_qty,
                :quantity_shipped
```

This is the scope that i am trying to create:

```
scope :shipped_qty_less_than_max_tolerance_qty, where("quantity_shipped < ?",self.booked_qty-self.cancelled_qty)
```

So what's the best way to write this scope? Thanks in advance!

Comment: ref link: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Are `quantity_shipped` and the others columns in the db or special methods in the model?

Comment: They all are in db. @iceman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After visiting all the possible links and trying out different possibilities here's what worked for me:

```
scope :shipped_qty_less_than_max_tolerance_qty, where("quantity_shipped < booked_qty-cancelled_qty")
```

Thank you everyone for their support.Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

The scope is correct, if you need to find out more about scopes in be sure to check [Rails Guides v3.2](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/active_record_querying.html#scopes)

Comment: scope wasn't correct mate that's why i asked. Anyways thanks for the help. That link helped me in understanding scopes better.